# Интеграция 2gis Api в проект с# (ГеоКлик)

Tags: javascript, c#, 2gis-api

Есть задача: встроить 2gis в программу так что бы работала функция ГеоКлик- получать информацию по адресу. Программа пишется на C#. Решил открывать через WebBrowser, но столкнулся с одной проблемой: карта отображается, но клики не работают. Искал решение, но ничего не нашел;
Вопрос: Как реализовать и можно ли реализовать подобное вообще?

Comment: решение нашлось?

Comment: Нет не нашлось. Я выбрал другой сервис "Openstreetmap". Там все работало.

Comment: у них есть платный апи, там вроде можно так

Comment: Не знаю даже. Я пытался какое то время, потом надоело и я начал искать альтернативы.

Comment: это точно, сам сейчас занимаюсь подобной интеграцией. как вариант, если вдруг актуально, есть ещё апи яндекс карт